# Compiling a GTK+ application for windows from linux

Tags: c, gcc, gtk, cross-compiling

I'm new to linux and have been learning gtk+ the past couple of days, and was wondering how you would go about compiling an application to run on windows instead of linux (ubuntu). I found [this](http://ricardo.ecn.wfu.edu/~cottrell/cross-gtk/) while doing a quick search but my knowledge of linux is non-existent at the moment so not sure how to proceed with the tutorial. Are there any alternative methods to do this?.

Comment: Are you having trouble with any particular *part* of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only compiled on Windows and used Cygwin to test 'nix versions (before going right into a 'nix OS and compiling), but looks like [this](http://www.astro.gla.ac.uk/~paulm/Cross/) might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling in other OS does not make sense while you can't disribute your binary without testing it on the target platform.
Then why not to compile on the same platform?